# Python 3.x reading UTF-16 files seems to reverse byte order

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-16

I'm trying to read Windows-generated UTF-16 files with Python. From what I understand, BOMs are FEFF. That's what this file starts with. However, when I read the file into Python, the bytes seem to get swapped.

```
(venv) [user]:~/consolidate$ head -c 16 temp.txt | od -x
0000000 feff 0022 0076 0065 0072 0073 0069 006f
0000020
(venv) [user]:~/consolidate$ python
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> with open('temp.txt', 'rb') as f:
...     str = f.readline()
...     print(str)
...
b'\xff\xfe"\x00v\x00e\x00r\x00s\x00i\x00o\x00n...
```

Using `head`, the first characters are `feff 0022`. Using Python, it appears to be `fffe2200`. What's going on here?

EDIT: my question is specifically about byte order. A few points:

- I don't want to decode the file. It's a 10GB file that needs to be split on a certain sequence.
- It appears to only be on the first line.
- Writing back to file conserves original order.

Example second line reading:

```
>>> with open('temp.txt', 'rb') as f:
...     str1 = f.readline()
...     str2 = f.readline()
...
>>> str2
b'\x00"\x00"\x00`\x00"\x00P\x
```

Comment: `b’...’` is a byte stream and you’re seeing the order of the bytes in the file, not the decoded characters.

Comment: Looks like an endianess issue. As per the answer of @Mr. J below, if you specify the encoding, Python should automatically recognize whether it's `UTF-16LE` or `UTF16-BE`.

Comment: @DavidMaze my question is specifically about the byte order. Why would it look like it has changed?

Comment: Because `od -x` appears to be decoding pairs of bytes in little-endian byte-swapped order.  `od -t x1` should dump out the bytes in the same order as in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three separate similar things going on here.  The file is a sequence of *bytes*, and the Python byte string `b'\xff\xfe"\x00v\x00e\x00...'` shows things in the same order the bytes are in in the file:

```
FF FE 22 00 76 00 65 00
```

When you ran `od -x`, it grouped pairs of bytes into *16-bit numbers*.  On x86 systems the standard byte ordering for 2-byte 16-bit numbers is for the least-significant byte ("ones byte") to be first and the most-significant byte ("256s byte") to be second (in Python, `n=b[0]+256*b[1]`).  So you get this *little-endian* decoding:

```
FEFF  0022  0076  0065
```

Meanwhile, you want to decode this into Unicode *characters*.  So long as no character is above U+FFFF, the *UTF-16 little-endian (UTF-16LE) encoding* translates that same decoding into Unicode characters:

```
U+FEFF U+0022 U+0076 U+0065
<BOM>     "      v      e
```

What happens at the end of the line?  Let's consider the string `u'...",\n ...'` and do this exercise in reverse order.

```
   "      ,     \n   <SPC>
U+0022 U+002C U+000A U+0020
22 00  2C 00  0A 00  20 00
b'"\x00,\x00\n\x00 \x00'
```

Meanwhile: what happens if you don't actually think about the character encoding, and "split this on newlines"?  You'd see `[b'"\x00,\x00"', b'\n', b'\x00 \x00']`.  That looks like the first part is little-endian byte order (quote null comma null) but the last part is big-endian (null space).  But the second half isn't actually a valid UTF-16 string: it contains odd numbers of bytes, because the first byte is actually the second half of the newline.  That's what's happening when you call `readline`.

You have a couple of options to deal with this.  One, mentioned in another answer, is to `open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-16')` (without a "b" in the file mode).  Then Python will do the correct UTF-16 decoding (taking the byte-order mark into account) and you will get a character string.  Calls like `str.readline` will also do what you expect here.

You also said your goal is just to split the file.  If you know with absolute certainty that the file is UTF-16LE encoded (the first two bytes are definitely FF FE) then you could process it as a byte string (with mode `'rb'` as in the code in the question) and split it on the UTF-16-encoded byte sequence you want

```
everything = f.read()
lines = everything.split(b'\x0A\x00')
for line in lines:
  parts = line.split(b'\x3A\x26')
```

This is easier to do if you can read the entire file in one chunk; at 10 GB that could be tricky in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Add  encoding='utf-16' parameter to open with
 `open('temp.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-16')`

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly decode as low-endian with `utf-16-le` and you receive the BOM as expected:

```
>>> b'\xff\xfe"\x00v\x00e\x00r\x00s\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00'.decode('utf-16-le')
'\ufeff"version'
```

If you decode with `utf-16` it already removes the BOM:

```
>>> b'\xff\xfe"\x00v\x00e\x00r\x00s\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00'.decode('utf-16')
'"version'
```